# Running legal exec() or system() command always returns 127

Tags: php, system, exec

```
exec('whoami', $output, $ret);

echo $ret;
```

returns `127`

The command does work when applied directly to the command line.

Comment: Try using the full path, e.g., `exec('/usr/bin/whoami', $output, $ret);`

Comment: Anything in `$output`? If not, try running `whoami 2>&1` to collect STDERR as well and see if there are any useful error messages

Comment: @output: just an empty array. `whoami 2>&1` made no change.

Comment: @JasonCoco: no change, still returns 127

Comment: Check out [this very old thread](http://www.webhostingtalk.com/archive/index.php/t-386461.html), it addresses this exact problem and the solution is something of an edge case but demonstrates some of the weird things that can go wrong.

Comment: @DaveRandom: I'll have to check with my hosts about that. I'll keep you updated once I know something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The host had it running in safe mode. That is why the commands wouldn't work.